# Subversion local directory not a working copy

Tags: svn, repository, commit

I am trying to commit something to a subversion repo from my local directory but when I try to do this, I get:

```
svn: '/path/to/mylocal/directory' is not a working copy
```

I forgot what actual directory this repo is linked to. Is there a way for me to link it to my current local directory? I can checkout and checkin fine to the repo manually using svn checkout and svn checkin. But I can't commit or see svn status.

Comment: svn commit is same as checkin. Could you elaborate on the question? Are you able to commit from other directories but are facing the problem in a specific directory? Have you checked out the directory in question before trying to commit?

Comment: Your working copy *isn't* linked to a repository at this point. If you've forgotten what repository it's linked to, no one here can help you - you have to look at your repositories and figure it out.

Comment: solved, I don't know what I did but it's working now.